# system timers timer dispose problem

Tags: c#, timer, dispose

I am developing one chat application on c#,and on that we use system.timer.timer for frequently getting data for new request and zone request also.

all the thing is running fine but when ever i sign out from application then this system timer is still running on background and generate error.so what i do for dispose all system timer when signout.

Please help me for this.

thanks in advance

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: Getting a System.Timers.Timer to stop reliably is impossible, the threading race is unavoidable.  The Elapsed event is raised on a threadpool thread, there may be several of them pending but not yet executing when you call the Stop() method.  You need to make your event handler resilient to that or stop using this miserable timer.  Favor a synchronous timer whenever you can (Winforms Timer or WPF DispatcherTimer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I immagine you tried already `Stop()` and `Close()`. If so, solution could be: during the closing of you applicaiton to make `Sleep()` for a couple of seconds main thread to let to timer's thread release resources allocated before.

There could be also a bug in application, which blocks timer's thread for some reason, but it's difficult to say to me, you should check it by yourself.

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: @mayur: if you're going to close your app, it's better also to make a timer to release resources so call Close() too. If it doesn't help, for some multithreading wierd problem, you can try to sleep your amin app thread to give a chance to Timer's thread to release allocated resources. This is only in case, if you call Stop()->Close() and still get a problem.

Comment: @Mayur - He suggested to manually stop the timer when you close your application.  He also suggested that you might have a blocking behavior within your code.

Comment: no i am taking about window application.and there is signout btn available on all page so when i click on signout at that time i want to close all the open form and also dispose timer but when i close the form but system timer is still running on background

Comment: @mayur: this means that my answer is still valid :)

Comment: but in my case when i am close the timer or stope the timer then also this will fire the elapse event this i cant find why this is happen.please help me for this.

Comment: Stop has not immediaty effect on timer, it's kind of "sign" for timer to stop when it is able to stop. So may be just before closing your app, and after that you call Stop()-> Close() delay your main thread for e second/two to let to thread to free allocated resources, and check yuor thread code.

Comment: thank friend my perpose is solved for that i sleep my main application thread for some second and on clossing event i dispose the timer object that is must other wise this will run every time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `Stop()` when you sign out.

Comment: That completely depends on how your application is built.  You may want to pass the page instances to each other or use a static `SignOut` event and handle it on every page with a timer.

Comment: @Mayur - Please explain exactly what you mean by "another page" as this would indicate you are talking about ASP.NET application.

Comment: no i am taking about window application.and there is signout btn available on all page so when i click on signout at that time i want to close all the open form and also dispose timer but when i close the form but system timer is still running on background...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's something else that's blocking your program. System.Timers.Timer creates a thread in the threadpool, meaning its a background thread, meaning it shuts down when your main thread does.

I think it's in the requests you do in your timer_elapsed function, which runs on your main thread.